# Generate all possible permutations of string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, ruby-on-rails-3, permutation, combinatorics

I have a long string in which each character has a specified number of options. For a shorter example, lets say I have a 4 character string.  The first character can be a number 1-6, the second character can be 1-5 or a-e, the third character can only be a or b, and the fourth character can be 0-9 or a-z.  How can I pragmatically generate a list or array of all possible permutations of my string using Ruby (RoR)?  A space can also be used for any of the characters.

So an example of the string could be:

```
1aaz
21b0
21 0
1 a1
```

Comment: What code have you written to solve this?

Comment: The Code in the chosen answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple solution:

```
strform = [%w(1 2 3 4 5 6), %w(1 2 3 4 5 a b c d e), %w(a b), %w(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z)]
strform[0].product(*strform[1..-1]).map(&:join)
```

Comment: Is it possible to use %w and include a blank space `" "` in each character position, or would I have to spell out the arrays in long form?

Comment: @sabrams: Yes. Something like this: `%w(a b \ )` (that's a backslash space).

Comment: If it's OK to modify `strform`, `strform.shift.product(*strform)..` is a nice way to do this.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: That's interesting.